# Cyclic subgroups and their cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

If a subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic, then is the group that contains this cyclic subgroup also cyclic?

Answer (score 2):

No.
A group generated by one element is always cyclic.
Take for example $S_3$ and its cyclic subgroup $\langle(12)\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact, any group whatsoever is a union of cyclic subgroups.